# Create a nuspec file that uses all the default behaviour but adding one additional file

Tags: nuget-package, nuget-spec

I want to have a `nuspec` file that automatically reads all the info from `packages.config` and so on, building up all the dependencies, but also includes just one single additional file.

Is there a way to do this?

For example, here is a `nuspec` file that does almost what I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <metadata>
    <id>My.Project</id>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <owners>Me</owners>
    <authors>Me</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <title>My.Project</title>
    <description>My.Project</description>
    <frameworkAssemblies />
    <copyright>Copyright ©  2015</copyright>
    <tags></tags>    
  </metadata>
</package>
```

If my project references ten `nuget` packages, the above `nuspec` file will detect that and add them as dependencies when I pack the package together.

But, the moment I add a `files` element then all the auto-linking to my other nuget dependencies stops:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <metadata>
    <id>My.Project</id>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <owners>Me</owners>
    <authors>Me</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <title>My.Project</title>
    <description>My.Project</description>
    <frameworkAssemblies />
    <copyright>Copyright ©  2015</copyright>
    <tags></tags>    
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="myfile.dll" target="lib\net45" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Without the auto-linking I effectively have to maintain two copies of all the dependencies for my project: one in the `csproj` file and one here.

There must be a way to do this?! I want to just add a single extra file to my package, via a nuspec.

Comment: Do you build your package using `pack myProj.csproj`?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to include an additional file in a package packed from a project, simply add the file to the project and set its **Build Action** to **Content**.
It will be added to the package under Content directory and on installing will be added to the consuming project.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Octopus Deploy?

If using Octopus Deploy this can be resolved by adding `/p:OctoPackEnforceAddingFiles=true`, which tells OctoPack to include the normal files on top of what's defined in `<files>..</files>`

Read this for more information

https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/nuget-packages/using-octopack/octopack-to-include-buildevent-files